# Need help to design page using css

Tags: css, html

I have requirement to design menu in round circle in a page as below shown image and its dynamic menu, icon can be generated based one requirement.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this one.

See working example below :  http://jsfiddle.net/6cygbd37/1/

```css
/*--CSS--*/
 .block {
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.circle {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 200px;
    color: white;
    height: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 200px;
    display: table;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.circle p {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 block">
            <div class="circle">
                <p>Some Text here Some text here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 block">
            <div class="circle">
                <p>Some Text here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 block">
            <div class="circle">
                <p>Some More Text here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is working code i got help internet, Help to achieve to below format please

Comment: try it with floats and margins

Comment: @AdarshMohan is  there is any library for that ?

Comment: @AdarshMohan with floats and margins will be kind static so

Comment: using libraries for such a small task is an overhead

Comment: @AdarshMohan can u help on this, its an urgent task i got .

Comment: @AdarshMohan suggest me how to search answer this question in google, what should i have to put in google to get result for this.

Comment: If you need only 7 circle I can position using percentage but if the circles are dynamic (that means can be less or more than 7) then is not possible

Comment: @Vincent1989  can u provide for 7 also okay , later i will work on making dynamic

Comment: Like this? [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nr75fgq9/)

Comment: @PatrickMlr Exactly . Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I have found answer my self for the question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #parent {
            position: relative;
            top: 200px;
            left: 200px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #parent div {
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
            -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
            transition: all 2s linear;
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
            border-radius: 100px;
            background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/e-commerce-and-business/104/New_Latest_Breaking-64.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            align-content:  stretch;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="parent">
            <div> item1 </div>
            <div> item2 </div>
            <div> item3 </div>
            <div> item4 </div>
            <div> item5 </div>
            <div> item6 </div>
            <div> item7 </div>
            <div> item8 </div>
            <div> item9 </div>            
        </div>

    <script>
        var type = 1, //circle type - 1 whole, 0.5 half, 0.25 quarter
            radius = '12em', //distance from center
            start = -90, //shift start from 0
            $elements = $('#parent >div'), numberOfElements = (type === 1) ? $elements.length : $elements.length - 1,
                        slice = 360 * type / numberOfElements;

        $elements.each(function (i) {
            var $self = $(this)
                , rotate = slice * i + start
                , rotateReverse = rotate * -1;

            $self.css({
                'transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg) translate(' + radius + ') rotate(' + rotateReverse + 'deg)'
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
.main-block {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.set {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}
.item,
.dummy {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}
.item {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
    <div class="set">
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="set">
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="set">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="set">
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="dummy"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try using `flexbox`, and it is responsive too.

```
.all-circles .row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.all-circles .row .block{
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.all-circles .row .block+.block{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.all-circles .row .block+.block{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.all-circles .row .block.r2,
.all-circles .row .block.r6{
    padding-left: 20%;
}

.all-circles .row .block.r3,
.all-circles .row .block.r7{
    padding-right: 20%;
}

.all-circles .row .block.r4{

}

.all-circles .row .block.r5{

}
```

Working example
[here](https://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/qPoxQz).

Comment: flex is a css3 property.. It wont work on older browsers.

Comment: which older browsers you need to support?

Comment: dont just simply see the people arround you.. there are people who are still using ie in windows xp (even though support where ended).

Comment: It depends if the audience of the website, newer properties have more flexibility and is good for making responsive website these days.

Comment: not gona start a debate here. I just wanna remind you of older browser support. never said your answer is wrong.. cheers.

Comment: I'm aware of that, no matter how many years it passed the old technology will always be there, if we keep cater for to old technology things will never be improved.